# Failed build - path to project is a directory

Tags: maven-3

- The path to my project is /project/
- My build file structure is `src/main/package/subpackage/Class.java`
- My test file structure is `src/test/package/subpackage/Test.java`
- I would like my compiled code to be in `bin/main/package/subpackage/Class.class`
- Compiled test code in `bin/test/package/subpackage/Test.class`

My pom.xml has the entry

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/bin/main</outputDirectory>
  <testOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}/bin/test</testOutputDirectory>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

Running `mvn clean install` causes the following.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project Hello-Maven: Error loading property file '/project/': /project (Is a directory) -> [Help 1]

...

[Help 1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

---

Now I've tried the link, but it suggest that it's an issue with the plugins.

However, commenting this block out, and running `mvn clean install` again returns an almost empty jar file inside /project/target/Hello-Maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, containing only the pom and the manifest. Additionally, there aren't any plugins, only dependencies: junit and javafx.

EDIT: I realize that plugins specifically for running maven but finding information over why the error happens for "install" is difficult at best.